# Custom radiobutton with gap between first and second line

Tags: html, css

I am creating a custom radio button that can cope with long text. Normally the text would go under the circle but I have fixed that. The problem that I am now coping with is that there is a gap between the first and second line of the text.

This is causing due to the fact that the `:before` is having a height. Does anyone know a solution to this?

[JSFIDDLE Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ujf5mcyd/)

HTML:

```
<span class="radiobuttons-item"><input id="id656" type="radio" name="id653" value="id656"><label for="id656">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed bibendum suscipit tellus, at tristique nunc. Vestibulum nulla purus. onsectetur adipiscing elit. Sed bibendum suscipit tellus, at tristique nunc. Vestibulum nulla purus Vestibulum nulla purus. onsectetur adipiscing elit. Sed bibendum suscipit tellus, at tristique nunc. Vestibulum nulla purus</label></span>
```

CSS:

```
body{
   background-color: #86C8BC;
}
.radiobuttons-item input[type='radio'] {
    display: none;
}
.radiobuttons-item {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.radiobuttons-item input[type='radio'] + label {
    position: relative;
    line-height: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 80%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.radiobuttons-item input[type='radio'] + label:before {
    content: '';
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin-right: 18px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #fff;
    vertical-align: middle;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.1em white, 0 0 0 0.2em #54585A;
    border: 6px solid #fff;
    margin-left: -55px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
.radiobuttons-item input[type='radio']:checked + label:before {
    background: #008C8F;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated the css code:

```
body{
   background-color: #86C8BC;
}
.radiobuttons-item input[type='radio'] {
    display: none;
}
.radiobuttons-item {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.radiobuttons-item input[type='radio'] + label {
    position: relative;
    line-height: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 80%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.radiobuttons-item input[type='radio'] + label:before {
    position:absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin-right: 18px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #fff;
    vertical-align: middle;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.1em white, 0 0 0 0.2em #54585A;
    border: 6px solid #fff;
    margin-left: -55px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
.radiobuttons-item input[type='radio']:checked + label:before {
    background: #008C8F;
}
```